# Are sign languages on-topic

Tags: discussion, on-topic

A [question](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/95/what-are-effective-ways-to-memorize-sign-languages) related to sign language has been asked on this site.

Are sign languages treated as normal languages and are considered on-topic?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sign language should be allowed. Though you might not speak it, it is still a language and this topic can bring up some interesting posts in the future.

Basically, sign language should be allowed as it is a language, just used with hands and usually by those who can't speak, and all normal rules on questions will apply to questions about sign language.

Comment: Agreed. Let's wait for more feedback.

Answer (score 8):

Absolutely, it should be allowed. Sign language linguistics research is very active. I have a close friend who is a linguist and is currently at a British university; she is going to be starting her PhD in Cambodian Sign Language (in which she did field work in developing in Cambodia).

Look up her profile at: [Anastasia Bradford](http://www.uclan.ac.uk/staff_profiles/anastasia_bradford.php)

Comment: [Nicaraguan Sign Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicaraguan_Sign_Language) is a wonderful example of the linguisitic interest in sign language and language creation and emergence.

Comment: Link is now broken

Answer (score 3):

Sign language is a means of communicating, other than in standard English, and should therefore be on topic here.