# What should our On-Topic Help Center section say?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

As @WBT has [thankfully reminded us](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/518/13), this community has not yet created an official [on-topic definition for the Help Center](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Almost exactly a year ago, @fi12 started this discussion [here](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/247/13), too.  Lets try to finish it this time!

By now regulars seem to have a pretty good sense of what is and is not on-topic here, but lets formalize this a bit.

I'd like this post to be a place to post on-topic and off-topic items for discussion, one per answer.  (I'll provide a few myself, to get discussion started, and provide examples).

Please post both on-topic and off-topic examples, and your suggested wording.  And leave comments to discuss and work out the best wording.  In a week or so, I, or one of the other mods, can aggregate the responses into the Help Center document.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [this](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247/what-should-our-help-center-documentation-contain) question that I asked one year ago.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @fi12!  I've marked that one as a duplicate of this one, not because it was inferior, but simply because a year has passed, and we've changed our on/off-topic expectations a bit as a community. Feel free to merge any relevant bits from that Q/A into answers here if you feel so inclined.

Comment: Ok, soo... when are these suggestions considered finalized?

Comment: @Hatchet: I think we can consider them final enough to add them to the help center. Should I do that, or would you like to?

Comment: @Flimzy Go ahead

Comment: @Hatchet: [done](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put the new [On-Topic text](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) live.  Please feel free to create a new post if you think something should be expanded or edited.

> **Language Learning Stack Exchange** is for students, teachers, polyglots, and anyone interested in the techniques of language acquisition.
>
> Questions on the following topics are welcome here:
>
> - Questions about learning any *human* language, including [unspoken](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34/13) and [constructed](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/a/202/13) languages.
> - Questions regarding definite obstacles faced by anyone learning a language.
> - Questions regarding specific language learning techniques or resources, and their effectiveness in comparison to others.
> - Requests seeking books, studies, web sites, or other resources supporting the scientific basis for any aspect of language study.
> - Questions seeking hard-to-find learning resources for a specific language. Be as specific as possible.
>
> But please don't ask questions about the following topics, which are deemed off-topic here:
>
> - Questions about grammar, spelling, phonetics, or other aspects of a specific language. Such questions are better asked at one of the [language-specific Q&A sites](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/438/13).
> - Questions about non-human languages, such as those used by [animals](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/a/151/13) or [machines](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/45/13).

Comment: Have you seen @fi12's suggestion regarding teaching? That should definitely also be on topic.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbeI hadn't seen it. Thanks for drawing my attention. The suggested changes have now been incorporated.

Answer (score 6):

## On-Topic

- Questions regarding certain language learning techniques or resources, and their effectiveness in comparison to others.

Answer (score 6):

## On-Topic

- Questions regarding definite obstacles you're facing in your L2 acquisition.

Answer (score 3):

## On-topic

- Requesting resources such as books, studies, PDF's, websites for on-topic reasons to back up answers in topics such as:

  - Proving the effectiveness of a technique(s)
  - Scientific reasons behind language learning guidelines or tips
  - Scientific effects of a trait on the acquisition of learning
  - How one affects the other

Please make sure that this is [reference-request](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) not [resource-request](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request).

Answer (score 2):

I like the completed list Flimzy has right now, but I'd like to suggest a few changes. The changes I have made are in bold.

For the first bullet point in the on-topic section:

- Questions about learning **or teaching techniques regarding** any human language, including unspoken and constructed languages. **If the question relates to a specific language but can be generally applicable to a
  wide variety of languages, it is considered to be on-topic.**

I think we should also add this bullet point to the on-topic section:

- **Using language learning or teaching software or technology
  (ex. Duolingo, Anki, etc.) in conjunction with the learning/teaching
  process**

I think this should be added to the off-topic section:

**- Translation or proofreading requests, and/or rating the quality of a translation**

Comment: Sorry I missed this until now; I have now incorporated the suggested changes. https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

## On-Topic

- Specific questions about learning resources for a specific language and/or target audience. Be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 0):

## Off-Topic

- Questions about grammar, spelling, phonetics, or other aspects of a specific language are off-topic. Such questions are better suited for the various [language-specific SE sites](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/438/13).

Comment: This is very broad. Would "(other than **learning** that language)" be a helpful insertion after "specific language?"

Comment: See also: [Meta question #1](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/1977)